# How can I create a carriage return in my C# string

Tags: c#, string, carriage-return

I have C# code that creates HTML. One particular piece of code creates a long string which is no problem for the browser. However when I look at the code with view > source it's difficult to see what's happening.

Is there some way that I can insert a carriage return or new line into my string so that it will make the string continue on the next line.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can put `\r\n` in your string.

Answer (score 21):

Along with `Environment.NewLine` and the literal `\r\n` or just `\n` you may also use a verbatim string in C#. These begin with `@` and can have embedded newlines. The only thing to keep in mind is that `"` needs to be escaped as `""`. An example:

```
string s = @"This is a string
that contains embedded new lines,
that will appear when this string is used."
```

Comment: This won't work if he's automatically generating the string, though, which is probably the case considering it's HTML.

Answer (score 15):

```
myString += Environment.NewLine;
```

or if you want to avoid potential String.Concat issue (e.g. for implementing this solution at scale):

```
myString = myString + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Probably not the best way of concatenating strings. Using the unary `+` operator will compile down to a call to `String.Concat`. This has some redirection involved. Maybe not a huge deal for a single line, but definitely not something you want to get into a pattern of doing.

Comment: I'd argue that `Environment.NewLine` is rarely the correct choice. That way the code behaves differently running on different OSes, something I'd rather avoid. (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: I don't think `+=` here is deserves the downvote. maybe a little advice "like yours", btw I know that you did not downvoted this

Comment: @Code: What I know is `Environment.NewLine` will write `\r\n` on Windows and `\r` on Linux. I thought that this is its benefits over writing `\n`. Why do you think that it will be a wrong choice?

Comment: Please don't argue about the performance of string concatenation here. This *might* matter in a measurable way if you did so hundreds of thousands of times, but come on — this is a *single* concatenation. **It just doesn't matter**.

Comment: I have zero problem with `+=` for strings. Yes, it "compiles down" to `string.Concat()`. Which is fine. I _do_ have a problem with `Environment.NewLine`. The problem is that it _does_ generate \n on Linux. So, what if my code is running on Linux and serving web pages to Windows users? Whereas `\r\n` will work in either case (though not sure about Mac users!)

Answer (score 4):

```
string myHTML = "some words " + Environment.NewLine + "more words");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<br /> works for me
```

So...

```
String body = String.Format(@"New user: 
 <br /> Name: {0}
 <br /> Email: {1}
 <br /> Phone: {2}", Name, Email, Phone);
```

Produces...

New user: 

 Name: Name

 Email: Email

 Phone: Phone

Comment: Works well for Web Interfaces

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual question, which is to add carriage returns when viewing the source of the HTML.

Comment: Indeed <br> is a different thing. Since whitespace is usually collapsed in HTML, one can assume the OP was going to display the HTML in a `<PRE>` or equivalent.  Or perhaps they only wanted it to be more readable when they viewed it _outside_ a web browser. In either case, `<br>` would only make it _less_ readable