# Overwrite current line in consle (equivalent of python "\r")

Tags: c#, stdout

In Python I'd use following for to overwrite current line with new text:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\r[Test]: Testing')
```

But how do I do this in C# I've tried this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\r[This is a test]");
Console.WriteLine("\r[This the next stage]");
```

But this code write on new line instead of overwriting the same line.

Comment: It would help if you indicated what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to emit a new line, then it depends on the platform. For windows, you have to have `\r\n`.

Comment: What, *specifically*, "didn't work" about it?

Comment: @JonathanWood I think the goal is to overwrite the previous string, so `\r\n` would be the wrong thing to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a carriage return in my C# string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806841/how-can-i-create-a-carriage-return-in-my-c-sharp-string)

Comment: @JonathanWood That would be if you were writing out a file and reading it with a program that only knew how to handle that particular new line separator.

Comment: I've completely changed question to match the answer. Feel free to revert (and consider to vote to close at that time).

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent code is:

```cs
Console.Write("\r[Test]: Testing");
```

Console.WriteLine will add a new line after your string is printed.