# Multi-line string in the style of a table with columns and word wrap

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to create a string that is styled as a table (with columns), such that the words in the first column wrap on a size limit?

For example:

```
 Test item that has a         $200     $300      
 long name

 Test short name              $100     $400

 Another test item            $400     $200

 Another loooooong            $600     $700
 name
```

I am currently trying to do it like this:

```
String.Format("{0,-50}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n", name, prices[0], prices[1], prices[2]);
```

But that doesn't do the word wrap.  The idea is for this to be one big string that is formatted, not separate strings.  Any ideas?

Comment: try \r \n ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806841/how-can-i-create-a-carriage-return-in-my-c-sharp-string

Comment: @KevinRaffay I want it to word wrap only when it reaches a certain size and only on the first column.  I am starting to believe it is not possible.

Comment: @DJBurb Its possible, you'll have to do the work yourself though, there isn't anything built in.

Comment: How are you rendering this?  Via Console, web, ???

Comment: @EricBurdo 3rd party document writer where I am passing in a string to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a moment so I threw a quick answer together.  It should be enough to get you going.

```
//Define how big you want that column to be (i.e the breakpoint for the string)
private const int THRESHOLD = 15;

//Formatter for your "row"
private const string FORMAT = "{0} {1} {2}\n";

public static string GetRowFormat(string name, decimal price1, decimal price2)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(name.Length > THRESHOLD) //If your name is larger than the threshold
    {   
        //Determine how many passes or chunks this string is broken into                    
        int chunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)name.Length / THRESHOLD);

        //Pad out the string with spaces so our substrings dont bomb out
        name = name.PadRight(THRESHOLD * chunks);

        //go through each chunk
        for(int i = 0; i < chunks; i++)
        {   
            if(i == 0) //First iteration gets the prices too
            {
                sb.AppendFormat(FORMAT, name.Substring(i * THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD), price1.ToString("C").PadRight(8), price2.ToString("C").PadRight(8));
            }
            else //subsequent iterations get continuations of the name
            {
                sb.AppendLine(name.Substring(i * THRESHOLD, THRESHOLD));
            }
        }           
    }
    else //If its not larger than the threshold then just add the string
    {
        sb.AppendFormat(FORMAT, name.PadRight(THRESHOLD), price1.ToString("C").PadRight(8), price2.ToString("C").PadRight(8));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I created a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/svpdhw)

Comment: Looks promising.  Let me give it a go.

Comment: There are probably ways to clean it up, but it should give you a good start.

Comment: I see what you are doing, but I was trying to get the whole table as one string, not separate strings.  *still playing with your answer though*

Comment: I just updated the fiddle so that all the strings are added to a string builder so the final result is just one string.

Comment: Works!!!!  I had to tweak it a little so that it wrapped the whole word instead of the last parts of the word, but this got me going. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//using (var writer = new StringWriter())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
{
    var regex = new Regex("(?<=\\G.{20})");

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var splitted = regex.Split(item.Name);

        writer.WriteLine("{0,-20}\t{1}\t{2}", splitted[0], item.Price1, item.Price2);

        for (int i = 1; i < splitted.Length; i++)
            writer.WriteLine(splitted[i]);
    }
    //Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
}
```